# How can I pull data from a plist by name?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory, core-data

I currently have an entity Exercise with attributes name, picture , muscle, etc.

When an exercise object is created and saved in my app (using core data), all these attributes are set from a dictionary in a .plist.  I now want to add descriptions (paragraph of text) but it doesn't make sense to add a description attribute to Exercise because there will be several of the same exercises and this may just waste space.

Is there a way I can create a new class, maybe exerciseDescription, that pulls the exercise name attribute from the selected exercise, and pull the corresponding description from a .plist?

I have almost 300 exercises and the plist I am currently pulling info from is an array of dictionarys for each muscle group which have an array of exercises in each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you create a new plist called ExerciseDescriptions.plist

[image: plist image]

Then implement something like this. *(I've not tested this code, it's just off my head)*

```
NSString *exerciseName = [exerciseEntity valueForKey:@"name"];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ExerciseDescriptions" ofType:@"plist"];

NSDictionary *exerciseDescription = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString *description = [exerciseDescription objectForKey:exerciseName];
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to create a (unique) file for each exercise description and store its handle (path?) in all cooresponding Exercise objects.

Comment: I have almost 300 exercises, so I don't think this is the best option.  The plist I am currently pulling info from is an array of dictionarys for each muscle group which have an array of exercises in each